# Installing R-devel via homebrew?

Tags: r, macos, homebrew

Is it possible to install the current R-devel version via homebrew?

I have already tried `brew install --devel r`, which does not work.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: I get `Error: No devel block is defined for r`

Comment: That doesn't look like the Linux name for the r-devel package. Other answers on SO suggest checking that you have installed gcc and gfortran with the correct versions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is indicated in the error message `Error: No devel block is defined for r`. If you run `brew edit r` you'll note there is no devel code block indicating the necessary url for the requested development version. Alternatively, you can append the `--HEAD` flag which will install the most recent r version with the latest commits available in the source repo. The difference between `--devel` and `--HEAD` flags is discussed in the Homebrew [formula cookbook](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#unstable-versions-devel-head). Similar info is also discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78984/what-does-brew-head-mean).